# Mapped type in TS doesn't return nested type

Tags: typescript

I have this sort of type :

```
type Schema = {
  name: {
    type: string
  }
  age: {
    type: number
  }
}
```

I would like to have a type which flatten it.

I expect this:

```
type MyType<Schema> = { 
  name: string
  age: number
}
```

But my try to express that doesn't succeed :

```
type UIType<Schema> = {
  [Key in keyof Schema]: Schema[Key].type
}
```

The error thrown is "Member 'type' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7008)".

Comment: `type UIType = {
  [Key in keyof Schema]: Schema[Key]['type']
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a type:

```js
type ObjTypeFromSchema<S extends Record<string, { type: any }>> = { 
    [K in keyof S]: S[K]["type"] 
}
```

then you should be able to throw any schema that conforms to `Record<string, { type: any }>` at it.

In your case

```js
type O = ObjTypeFromSchema<Schema>;
```

gives a type for `O` of:

```
{
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLxQN4CgoFQB2qyEAXDvoTaJJQM7ABOAlkQObUEC+3UqDhSo1a4YUQCuyAEYRm-Pn1x1oAeRkArACriAYswD2yeEjQAeGFAgAPYBCIATBlABKEOIeaPzTNpwAaHChVSlQiECgeAD5ozGCAbQBpKHYoAGsIEEMAM1gAXUoYZPyEgCJVMvyo3BVxKDV4jR19IxNEFFRLDrRo3AB6fsIAPQB+IA)